# Why isn't the overloaded method getting called?

Tags: c#, .net

I thought the method that is getting called is decided runtime, or have I missed something? Sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var magic = new MagicClass();
        magic.DoStuff(new ImplA());
        magic.DoStuff(new ImplB());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class MagicClass
{
    internal void DoStuff<T>(T input) where T : SomeBase
    {
        HiThere(input);
    }

    void HiThere(SomeBase input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base impl");
    }

    void HiThere(ImplA input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ImplA");
    }

    void HiThere(ImplB input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ImplB");
    }
}

abstract class SomeBase
{

}
class ImplA : SomeBase{}
class ImplB : SomeBase{}
```

I thought I would get:

```
ImplA
ImplB
```

as output but it prints `Base impl`. Is there anything I can do to get the overloaded method without casting the input?

Comment: Here is a pretty decent explanation why: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Overloads are chosen by the compiler. For the call here:

```
internal void DoStuff<T>(T input) where T : SomeBase
{
    HiThere(input);
}
```

it chooses the one with `SomeBase`, because that's all it has at compile time.

What you most probably want is overrides. This means that the different logic has to be put into the inheritors of SomeBase:

```
abstract class SomeBase
{
  abstract string Name { get; }
}
class ImplA : SomeBase{ override string Name { get { return "ImplA"; } } }
class ImplB : SomeBase{ override string Name { get { return "ImplB"; } } }

void HiThere(SomeBase input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input.Name);
}
```

Comment: Another possibility is that he wants to do [`double dispatch`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) or use the [`visitor pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: Or the use of `dynamic`: `HiThere((dynamic)input);` This moves the overload resolution to the runtime where the exact type of `input` is known.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: That's probably the best possible implementation of double-dispatch there is. :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Indeed, that would be a concrete implementation of double dispatch.

Answer (score 4):

Overloads are selected during compilation.
Overrides are selected during runtime.

Here, compilers only knows that T can be assigned to `SomeBase`, but nothing else. Actually, if it worked as you expected, you would be able to completely skip the `where T : SomeBase` part. The reason you need it is that compiler needs to know that information in order to check what can be called on the provided object.